# Encrypting just the Salesforce Email Field

Tags: web-services, encryption, salesforce, apex-code

Is there a way to encrypt just the email field in Salesforce? Any ideas would be great.  Using SFDC build in functionality or APEX, triggers or web services.

Thanks.

Comment: Apex now has encryption functions built-in that work pretty well, but can you clarify what you are trying to do? True encryption, or do you just want to obscure the visible address while on screen? Who needs to access the unencrypted data, and what steps do you expect they need to take to access it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So we want the email address to be encrypted at rest. So while the email address is not being viewed, it should be encrypted. Whenever a rep needs to look at the address, i.e. Case record, Contact record or sending emails the address should be decrypted.  The other use case is when a customer sends us an email, we need to encrypt that address before storing it within the Case record (at rest on the Case table). Does that clarify what I'm after? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce does support an "Text (Encrypted)" custom data type. You will have to contact Salesforce to get this enabled for your organization. A couple of things to note with encrypted fields:

- Encrypted fields are encrypted with 128-bit master keys and use the AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) algorithm.
- You can only store text, and a max length of 175 characters
- Encrypted data will be shown masked for all users except those with 'View Encrypted Data' permission

[The Salesforce documentation](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm)

[A cookbook that walks you through storing a SSN](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/storing-and-displaying-confidential-information)

Comment: Hi George, thanks for the answer. Salesforce won't encrypt the email field though correct?  I was told that this is the only field that they won't encrypt. Does that make sense?

Comment: Salesforce wont encrypt the out-of-box fields, such as on the Contacts object; the encrypted field is a custom field. You could potentially add a new Text(Encrypted) field to the Contact object and remove the built-in one from page layouts. This seems risky though as you're likely to break some existing functionality such as sending the Forgot My Password email. You could add an apex trigger that copies the email address from the custom field to the standard email field - again the standard field wouldn't be encrypted (although it wouldn't be displayed on the page layouts)